# Simple income/expenses accounting program

Tags: rust, finance

I've decided to start working on a budget application for the purposes of getting started on Rust. In its current form this program takes given expenses and income and tells the user whether they have a surplus, a deficit, or if they are breaking even. I will add more functionality to this program as I move along in the development process.

Did I respect every best practice in Rust ? Is there something I could improve ?

```
use std::io;
use std::process;

fn income_ask() -> String {
    println!("Add income? [y/n]: ");
    let mut add_income = String::new();
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut add_income)
        .expect("Failed to read input");
    return add_income;
}

fn income_sum(income_list: &Vec<u64>, income: &mut u64) {
    *income = income_list.iter().sum();
    println!("{}", income);
}

fn expense_ask() -> String {
    println!("Add expense? [y/n]: ");
    let mut add_expense = String::new();
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut add_expense)
        .expect("Failed to read input");
    return add_expense;
}

fn expense_sum(expense_list: &Vec<u64>, expenses: &mut u64) {
    *expenses = expense_list.iter().sum();
}

fn prompt_income(income_list: &mut Vec<u64>, income_name: &mut Vec<String>, income: &mut u64) {
    loop {
        let result = income_ask();
        if result.trim() == "y" {
            println!("Enter source of income. [Numbers Only]: ");
            let mut income_input = String::new();
            io::stdin()
                .read_line(&mut income_input)
                .expect("Failed to read input");
            let income_input: u64 = match income_input.trim().parse() {
                Ok(num) => num,
                Err(_) => continue,
            };
            income_list.push(income_input);

            println!("Enter income name. [Name Only]: ");
            let mut income_name1 = String::new();
            io::stdin()
                .read_line(&mut income_name1)
                .expect("Failed to read input");
            income_name.push(income_name1);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    income_sum(&income_list, income);
    println!("Total user income: {} ", income);
}

fn prompt_expense(expense_list: &mut Vec<u64>, expense_name: &mut Vec<String>, expenses: &mut u64) {
    loop {
        let result = expense_ask();
        if result.trim() == "y" {
            println!("Enter expense amount. [Numbers Only]: ");
            let mut expense_input = String::new();
            io::stdin()
                .read_line(&mut expense_input)
                .expect("Failed to read input");
            let expense_input: u64 = match expense_input.trim().parse() {
                Ok(num) => num,
                Err(_) => continue,
            };
            expense_list.push(expense_input);

            println!("Enter expense name. [Name Only]: ");
            let mut expense_name1 = String::new();
            io::stdin()
                .read_line(&mut expense_name1)
                .expect("Failed to read input");
            expense_name.push(expense_name1);
        } else {
            break;
        }
        expense_sum(&expense_list, expenses);
        println!("Total user expenses: {}", expenses);
    }
}

fn uservalue(income: u64, expenses: u64) {
    let valoutput: i64;
    valoutput = income as i64 - expenses as i64;
    if valoutput < 0 {
        println!(
            "You are in the negative, you have a deficit of {}",
            valoutput
        );
    } else if valoutput == 0 {
        println!("You have broken even, you are spending exactly as much as you make.");
    } else if valoutput > 0 {
        println!(
            "You are in the positive, you have a surplus of {}",
            valoutput
        );
    }
}

fn close_program() {
    println!("Exiting Program.");
    process::exit(1);
}

fn main() {
    let mut expense_list: Vec<u64> = Vec::new();
    let mut income_list: Vec<u64> = Vec::new();
    let mut expense_name: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
    let mut income_name: Vec<String> = Vec::new();
    let mut income: u64 = 0;
    let mut expenses: u64 = 0;

    loop {
        prompt_income(&mut income_list, &mut income_name, &mut income);
        prompt_expense(&mut expense_list, &mut expense_name, &mut expenses);

        uservalue(income, expenses);
        println!("Would you like to run another analysis? [y/n]: ");
        let mut another = String::new();
        io::stdin()
            .read_line(&mut another)
            .expect("Failed to read input");

        if another.trim() == "y" {
            income = 0;
            expenses = 0;
            expense_list.clear();
            income_list.clear();
            expense_name.clear();
            income_name.clear();
        } else {
            close_program();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote some of your program to make it more idiomatic in Rust. I tried to comment significant changes I made, but if you have any questions about why I changed things, you can click "add a comment" below my answer. Side note: the comments I made aren't necessarily good code comments (as in I wouldn't keep them in the code, they're just to explain to you the changes)

```
// Pulling out this repeated code into one function reduces repetition.
fn ask(buf: &mut String, prompt: &str, guide: &str) {
    use std::io::{stdin, stdout, Write};

    // Using print (not println) lets you have the input seen on the same line.
    print!("{} [{}]: ", prompt, guide);
    // Since stdout is line-buffered, you must flush if you are not printing a new line.
    stdout().flush().expect("Failed to flush output");
    stdin().read_line(buf).expect("Failed to read input");
}

fn ask_name(prompt: &str) -> String {
    let mut buf = String::new();
    ask(&mut buf, prompt, "Name only");
    buf
}

// Here we keep asking until we get a valid number.
fn ask_numeric(prompt: &str) -> u64 {
    let mut buf = String::new();
    loop {
        ask(&mut buf, prompt, "Numbers only");
        if let Ok(num) = buf.trim().parse() {
            return num;
        }
        buf.clear();
        println!("Try again.");
    }
}

// Here we may also want to keep asking until we get either y/n, to be more exact.
fn ask_yn(prompt: &str) -> bool {
    let mut buf = String::new();
    ask(&mut buf, prompt, "y/n");
    buf.trim().eq_ignore_ascii_case("y")
}

// By grouping the name and amount for each entry, we make it more explicit that the vec of names
// and vec of amounts are paired together. We could have just used a tuple like (String, u64), but
// since this is what the program revolves around, its certainly worth making a struct for.
#[derive(Clone, Debug)]
struct Record {
    name: String,
    amount: u64,
}

fn prompt_income(income_list: &mut Vec<Record>) -> u64 {
    // Using our ask functions simplify this loop greatly.
    while ask_yn("Add income?") {
        income_list.push(Record {
            amount: ask_numeric("Enter income amount."),
            name: ask_name("Enter income name."),
        });
    }
    // Here we map from Record to u64, so that we sum the amounts.
    let income = income_list.iter().map(|r| r.amount).sum();
    println!("Total user income: {} ", income);
    income
}

// Note that this function is almost identical to prompt_income, this would be another good target
// to deduplicate.
fn prompt_expense(expense_list: &mut Vec<Record>) -> u64 {
    while ask_yn("Add expense?") {
        expense_list.push(Record {
            amount: ask_numeric("Enter expense amount."),
            name: ask_name("Enter expense name."),
        });
    }
    let expenses = expense_list.iter().map(|r| r.amount).sum();
    println!("Total user expenses: {} ", expenses);
    expenses
}

fn uservalue(income: u64, expenses: u64) {
    use std::cmp::Ordering;

    // Here we always subtract the smaller number from the bigger one, which keeps us from having
    // to worry about casting to signed types and having any problems with overflow, etc. We
    // compare the numbers first, then do different things based on that.
    match income.cmp(&expenses) {
        Ordering::Less => {
            println!(
                "You are in the negative, you have a deficit of {}",
                expenses - income
            );
        }
        Ordering::Equal => {
            println!("You have broken even, you are spending exactly as much as you make.")
        }
        Ordering::Greater => {
            println!(
                "You are in the positive, you have a surplus of {}",
                income - expenses
            );
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut expense_list = Vec::new();
    let mut income_list = Vec::new();

    loop {
        let income = prompt_income(&mut income_list);
        let expenses = prompt_expense(&mut expense_list);

        uservalue(income, expenses);

        if !ask_yn("Would you like to run another analysis?") {
            // This break gets us out of this loop and continues main, eventually just exiting
            // the program normally.
            break;
        }

        expense_list.clear();
        income_list.clear();
    }

    // In the close_program function you had, you were exiting with status 1 which actually
    // signifies an error. By just letting main end, we exit normally. You could put a println here
    // if you wanted.
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input! I will take a look into it!